# Using Bash scripting for web scraping over python libraries?

Tags: python, bash, curl, sed, web-scraping

I am trying to get more information from  experienced people doing web scraping in general, I am getting into web scraping using Python libraries. At the same time, I noticed some people are using simple Bash, and using commands for web scraping such as `wget, curl, sed, grep, awk`.

These commands seem to be much cleaner in scripting than using Python libraries for web scraping.

What are your takes on this? Do you see any advantage of using python libraries over Bash that I am not getting? Or even using Python with Bash to accomplish web scraping?

Comment: Well, it's a question of coding style. In general, if you CAN use a Python lib for a specific task, use it over the Bash commands.

Comment: Yes, there is a huge advantage to running *one* program instead of *many* programs.

Comment: well, python needs the libraries though. is not like you can use straight python.

Answer (score 1):

[BeautifulSoup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/) and [Requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/) are the best tools out there for programmatic scraping.  They're widely used, updated frequently, and are focused on ease of use (the motto of requests is `HTTP for Humans`).

Comment: have you seen what is possible with curl or get? with one line of command?

Comment: Most experienced programmers are familiar with curl and get. The point is that using python is easier to use, easier to read, and more maintainable. There is a reason professionals throughout the industry use it. If you just need a script to get a page from the internet, by all means use bash. But does bash have database drivers? Does it have modules? There are many advantages to using python.

Comment: I think another point in Python's favor is that JSON has become more common as a data format.  Sure, for a one off download of a webpage, curl is battle-hardened and an excellent tool, but imagine crawling a REST API with `curl` & other unix tools?  You could take time to learn `jq`'s syntax, or you could just use `requests`, call `r.json()` and finish your task.

Comment: yes, these are good points. I guess i was trying to get more info as to whether invest more time with bash or more time with python libraries, but in the end, I guess it  will be based on the knowledge and tools available. not so much on using one particular language over the other.

Answer (score 0):

With Python you can also scrape sites rendered with JavaScript using selenium und a headless browser like PhantomJS. Maybe this is possible with bash scripting too, but the more complext your code gets the bigger the advantage of the clarity of python IMHO.

Comment: Thanks, I did not thought about dealing with javascript.